# No envía email de confirmación al usuario registrado - No devuelve error y lleva a la página principal

Tags: python, django

Se pretende que al registrarse un nuevo usuario se le envíe un email de confirmación. Tras rellenar y darle a aceptar, no devuelve ningún error, pero tampoco envía el email de confirmación que debería enviar al usuario. Eso sí, lleva al usuario a la página principal.
¿Qué ocurre?

Como servidor de correo tengo configurado SendGrid (sí que funciona el servidor de correo ya que el formulario de contactar si envía el email).

views.py

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()

            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Activate Your MySite Account'
            message = render_to_string('account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            user.email_user(subject, message)

            return redirect('account_activation_sent')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})


def account_activation_sent(request):
    return render(request, 'account_activation_sent.html')


def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.profile.email_confirmed = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        return render(request, 'account_activation_invalid.html')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import datetime


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)

def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()

class TokenToUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=34, null=True, blank=False)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                verbose_name='Registration date')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

forms.py

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','first_name','last_name','email','password1','password2']

        help_texts = {
        'username' : None,
        'first_name': None,
        'last_name': None,
        'email': None,
        'password1': None,
        'password2': None,
        }


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['username'].label = "Nombre de usuario"
        self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['first_name'].label = "Nombre"
        self.fields['last_name'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['last_name'].label = "Apellido"
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['email'].label = "Email"
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['password1'].label = "Password"
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['password2'].label = "Confirmar password"

    field_order = [
        'username',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'password1',
        'password2']
```

Comment: De todo el código que has puesto ¿dónde se supone que se envía el correo? No veo nada que sugiera que se está enviando, como no sea dentro de `user.email_user()`, código que no muestras.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que el metodo email_user() que estas llamando es el metodo definido en la clase models.User del auth de Django, si es asi, entonces te pregunto:

Si definiste la variable DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL en tu settings, si puedes comparte tu settings para ver si todo esta bien definido? Ya que es necesario DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL si no defines el parametro from_email de email_user()

Podrías intentar pasando manualmente el parámetro from_email en el metodo email_user() y ver si sale el email https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.email_user